# Strange error message in dev tools - Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I try too access object :

```
balance_Table.TEXTBOX.font
```

and everything is ok but program breaks in this line (top / last error msg in console) . Value is "24px Verdana" - this is regular .

look at this screenshot :

[image]

Comment: if it is not a misreported line number, could it be an error in a property setter that the debugger just does not step into?

Comment: I use try/catch just for fast fix . This code execute from online fiddleJs i have lot of res missed and eval staff. It is too much for perfect code debug...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens to me all the time. The problem has been that Chrome fails to report the correct line where the code is failing, but it should be a line around that number, give or take 15 lines or so.

What I do when part of the javascript is dynamically generated, is I copy all the source from Chrome and paste it in a syntax sensitive editor (I use PhpStorm, CTRL+SHIFT+ALT+INS inserts a scratch js file with syntax highlighting and correction), it usually finds the error very quickly for me, in case it is a missing semicolon or something like that.

Comment: please don't downvote if this is not the solution to your particular problem, as it might be the solution for other people searching for similar simptoms